# Generate Unique Key from n integers

Tags: key, unique

i want to generate one unique integer from N other integers. Is there a better way then add the minimum  and then get bit's used for this integer and shift them and and do the same with the N other integers ?

In my example i have 3 integers and need one unique key.

```
a: min=875 max=102504
b: min=103320030 max=1089520383
c: min=706 max=9909
```

i was reading https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/create-unique-number-from-2-numbers but its only for two integers...

Greetings

Comment: There are many other ways to do it, but there are different weaknesses/strengths to each. You could exponentiate (possibly using modular operations) - e.g. {a, b, c} -> (a^b)^c - concatenate, use various bitwise operations (shifts, and/or/xor/etc). Most methods leave at least the possibility of collisions - two sequences generating the same output. If you absolutely can't tolerate that, a counter may be the best you can do. I think further details about how you intend to use the outputs, what ranges the inputs have (both per-number as well as sequence length) and other info might be useful...

Comment: As this question is an iteration of the one in the link you provided It might be better asked in http://math.stackexchange.com/. Once you have an algorithm you have settled on, then you might ask hear how to program it in a specific programming language.